# Is it good programming practice to have a function return a dictionary ? (so that old code doesn't break)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am touching an old Python function, which currently returns a list. It now needs to return a status code too.

But this change will break some existing code, right ?

So I was thinking.....WHAT IF (from now on) all my functions return a dictionary instead ? The callers would then be able to use the piece of data they need, and old code wouldn't break if I decide to add a few more outputs at some point.

I wonder if this is something that has been practiced before ? Am I missing something here, or maybe this is an overkill ?

EDIT:

Here is an example :

```py
def GetDataFromWeb(url):
    X = GetXFromWeb(url)     # This function takes 5 seconds to complete
    Y = GetYFromWeb(url)     # This function also takes 5 seconds to complete
    return X + Y
```

Now suppose we need the product X*Y as well. One solution is to have another function do the job:

```py
def GetDataFromWeb_2(url):
    X = GetXFromWeb(url)     # This function takes 5 seconds to complete
    Y = GetYFromWeb(url)     # This function also takes 5 seconds to complete
    return X * Y
```

but there is a clear waste of time when we need both the sum and the product (because the costly web requests are called twice)

So we eventually resort to :

```py
def GetDataFromWeb(url):
    X = GetXFromWeb(url)     # This function takes 5 seconds to complete
    Y = GetYFromWeb(url)     # This function also takes 5 seconds to complete
    return (X + Y, X * Y)
```

**But now, code that uses the original version of GetDataFromWeb() will break.**

What I am considering goes along these lines:

```py
def GetDataFromWeb(url):
    X = GetXFromWeb(url)     # This function takes 5 seconds to complete
    Y = GetYFromWeb(url)     # This function also takes 5 seconds to complete
    return {'sum' : X + Y}
```

which can always be augmented to

```py
def GetDataFromWeb(url):
    X = GetXFromWeb(url)     # This function takes 5 seconds to complete
    Y = GetYFromWeb(url)     # This function also takes 5 seconds to complete
    return {'sum' : X + Y, 'product' : X*Y }
```

and old code will still work :

```py
sum = GetDataFromWeb(url)['sum']
```

Comment: It sounds.. like shooting a mole with a 35mm cannon. API are contracts and any breaking change MUST be accounted for. I would say that it is rare that the only change is 'an additional return value'. A method that starts with a single non-compound return value is very different than a method that starts with a complex object.

Comment: Dictionaries are in fact more extensible than lists and definitely classes. That said, if you're breaking someone's API you should be careful. I rarely use classes or lists in python. I find dictionaries and sets/tuples to be much nicer to play with (unless I hit  a specific use case).

Comment: I mostly agree with @user2864740 on that. Now, if your use case really demands it, you could wrap function results in a standard dict or object. I've seen some web APIs do it (can't name them though).

Comment: However, if you just want to add the possibility of an error or success status, you probably should use exceptions.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. @user2864740 I agree that adding more return values is hardly the only change, but it is the one that breaks existing code. @ araraonline The status code is just an example, it could be anything really.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the Adaptor pattern?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_adapter.htm

> Adapter pattern works as a bridge between two incompatible interfaces.
>   This type of design pattern comes under structural pattern as this
>   pattern combines the capability of two independent interfaces.
>
> This pattern involves a single class, which is responsible to join
>   functionalities of independent or incompatible interfaces. A real life
>   example could be the case of a card reader, which acts as an adapter
>   between memory card and a laptop. You plug in the memory card into the
>   card reader and the card reader into the laptop so that memory card
>   can be read via the laptop.
>
> The adapter design pattern helps to work classes together. It converts
>   the interface of a class into another interface based on requirement.
>   The pattern includes a speciation a polymorphism which names one name
>   and multiple forms. Say for a shape class which can use as per the
>   requirements gathered.

---

EDIT

It might be more simple to use the keyword argument.

```
def do(u, ops={'sum': sum}):
  x = u[0]
  y = u[1]
  if len(ops) == 1:
    return list(ops.values())[0]((x, y))
  else:
    return {k: o((x, y)) for k, o in ops.items()}

print(do([1, 2]))
print(do([1, 2], ops={'prod':lambda x: x[0] * x[1]}))
print(do([1, 2], ops={'sum': sum, 'prod':lambda x: x[0] * x[1]}))
```

Or even simpler.

```
def do(u, flag_new=False):
  x = u[0]
  y = u[1]
  if flag_new is False:
    return x + y
  else:
    return {'sum': x + y, 'prod': x * y}

print(do([1, 2]))
print(do([1, 2], flag_new=True))
```

Comment: Thank you, but not very flexible IMO.